# how to get azure appfabric nettcprelaybinding working in an azure webrole

Tags: azure, appfabric

you would think this would be easy since Azure Appfabric is supposedly part of Azure.

Firstly Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll isnt on the VM; fixed that

Now the tcprelay bind fail: the binding type is unknown. So I called

```
    RelayConfigurationInstaller.AddRelayConfiguration(config);
```

In Application_Start

Nope, same error. So I copied relayconfigurationinstaller.exe to the VM, ran it using RDP.

Nope, same error.

Any ideas?

EDIT: This is the error I am talking about

```
ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration binding extension 'system.serviceModel/bindings/netTcpRelayBinding' could not be found. Verify that this binding extension is properly registered in system.serviceModel/extensions/bindingExtensions and that it is spelled correctly.]
```

answer: http://www.wadewegner.com/2010/05/net-framework-4-0-and-the-azure-appfabric-sdk/

the installers set the v2 clr config files; I am using v4 clr.

EDIT: well that binary works now but the API calls still dont work.  (which is the preferred way of doing things)

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty sure if this helps, but you need to add the AppFabric WCF extensions on your machine.config or yor app.config.

Comment: Where do you get these extensions? Can you download them?

Comment: If you installed the AppFabirc SDK on your machine they should be in your machine.config. But don't now currently since there's no separated AppFabric SDK...